# Separar JQuerys e Css

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Possuo uma `index.php` que usa os seguintes `JQuery` e `CSS`:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
```

E a partir desta `index`, chamo uma segunda página `example.php` através de um link normal sem passar formulários nem nada e que usa outro `JQuery` e `CSS`:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Minha dúvida é:

O `JQuery` e `CSS` da `index` está afetando e sobrescrevendo o da página `example.php`.

Como posso consertar isso ?

Comment: Poste o código HTML dos elementos e qual o css aplicado à eles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi, <strike>Diego</strike> Lucas! Blz?

A example.php está sendo chamada *dentro* do conteúdo da **index.php**?
Digo isso porque se a **example.php** for outra página, sendo chamada no browser **separadamente** da index.php, o jQuery e CSS não tem porque afetá-la.

Mas... Se você estiver inserindo novos scripts na index.php, através de uma chamada da página **example.php**, recomendo **não** chamar novamente o jQuery.

Dê uma olhada neste post do **William Bruno** que fala um pouco sobre conflitos de script: http://wbruno.com.br/jquery/noconflict-jquery-usando-2-bibliotecas-javascript-alias/

Se forem páginas chamadas separadamente, inclua normalmente os scripts e estilos que você quiser. Eles devem ser carregados normalmente e **sem nenhuma ligação** com a index.php.

Abs.

---

#### Complementando

Visto que as páginas têm ligação, você pode identificar as tags p/ manipulá-las.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script id="jqMobileJs" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link id="jqMobileCss" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
```

E na página exemplo.php

```
<script>
var novoJs = "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js";
var novoCss = "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css";
$('#jqMobileJs').attr('src', novoJs);
$('#jqMobileCss').attr('href', novoCss);
</script>
```

Obs.: Acredito que seja melhor você identificar de onde está vindo a chamada dos arquivos da **index.php** e separar isso da **exemplo.php**. De qualquer forma, deixei esse código aqui, para que você possa testar.

Comment: Me chamo Lucas, tudo bom e vc ? Mas, infelizmente sua resposta não me ajudou. Como expliquei na minha pergunta, a index chama a example.php através de link e a intenção é que as páginas possuam estilos diferentes.

Comment: Perfeito, Lucas! Mas se você tem 2 páginas diferentes, basta fazer referência aos arquivos normalmente. Para cada página será chamado uma folha de estilo diferente. E estas, por sua vez, terão os estilos diferentes (a não ser que tenha ligação entre elas).

O projeto está sendo desenvolvido/mantido em qual plataforma? Tem alguma URL, que você possa compartilhar, para que eu possa acompanhar este código e as chamadas?

Comment: Então @romulobastos, após alguns testes aqui verifiquei o seguinte. Se adiciono a propriedade target="_blank" ele passou a funcionar. O que prova que as páginas estão ligadas de alguma forma, gostaria de carregar na mesma página e "resetando" os estilos e refêrencias.